# Problema con los controladores en php

Tags: php

Me gutaría saber por qué cuando introduzco 2 controladores en una misma vista me da el siguiente error.

**Fatal error: Cannot redeclare AbrirBaseDatos() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Model\conexion.php:5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema de llaves\Sistema-llaves\SistemaLlaves 1.1.1\Model\conexion.php on line 3**

Inclusión en la vista

```
<?php
  include "../Template/MenuTemplate.php";
  include "../Controller/RegAcademiaController.php";
  include "../Controller/RegProfesorController.php";
?>
```

Comment: Seguramente estas anidando includes a los mismos archivos desde los archivos que estás incluyendo. Mira de cambiar los include() por include_once() para que solo se cargen una vez y no se produzuca esa repetición de definición de funciones o clases

Comment: Gracias!! Me ha servido